# Pathfinding : Jump Point Search - Straight Moves vs Diagonal Moves

Tags: algorithm, point, path-finding, a-star

Planning working on a 2D RTS, I tried to learn how Astar works.
Indeed, I found articles explaining how Astar could be optimized coupling it with binary heaps, and algorithms taking advantages of Path symmetry, like [Jump Poin Search algorithm](http://harablog.wordpress.com/2011/09/07/jump-point-search/).
I tried to [implement](https://github.com/Yonaba/Jumper) Jump Point Search, and it runs fine. I even made some benchmarks tests with maps from MovingAI.

Yet there is a problem. Everything runs fine when diagonal moves are allowed.When disabled, no path is returned...

It may be linked to the way I implementd it, then I'm all asking...In general, how would you oblige the algorithm (JPS) to search for path involving only straight moves (not diagonals moves) to reach a goal?

Comment: A* doesn't care about what directions you allow so it's obviuosly an implementation detail. Include some sample code you've written.

Comment: The code consists of several files, but the main file can be found here: [https://github.com/Yonaba/Jumper/blob/master/Lib/jumper.lua] Jumper...

Comment: The link doesn't work. Also, diagonal/straight is not related to the abstract search algorithm but how you organize the lattice (system of intersections) where you conduct the search.

Comment: Thanks for these answers...Sorry about the link, I messed with Markdown formatting...here is the link goot link. https://github.com/Yonaba/Jumper/blob/master/Lib/jumper.lua              Would you mind take a look ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jump point search NEEDS diagonals enabled to work. In state algorithm is in, this is one of its limitations. Also, you wont be able to make your terrain distinguishable (mud = penalty to movement, etc.) since this would destroy symmetries. I suggest you stick to A* and try to gain performance by terrain presentation (mesh, waypoints). Or maybe check HPA*.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to create a version of JPS that uses only cardinal directions if you have it send sub-searches(as you would with the diagonal movement) along the directions perpendicular to the original direction. Doing that, it will be able to find when a node at a given location will find a node further ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Well, technically speaking, if no diagonal moves are allowed, then your optimal heuristic is Manhattan Distance. That means that A* will find na answer with a minimum of moves. Representing your map in a grid with each node having a onOpen and onClosed booleans, as opposed to using a closed list, is a HUGE optimization. In addition, if you use std make heap, push_heap and pop heap, you can get the cheapest node with cost log n (1 to pop + log n to sort = O(logn)), which scales much better than using a vector.